# alguem sabe o porque deste erro?

Tags: c

quando tento introduzir qualquer valor carácter o programa da skip na opçao e nem tenho a chance de escrever alguem sabe o porque?

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <ctype.h>

    int i=0;
    struct pessoas {
    char nomealuno[60];
    int numeromeca;
    char rua[90];
    char curso[200];
    int dia;
    int mes;
    int ano;
    int nporta;
    int codigopostal1;
    int codigopostal2;
    int num;
    };

     .....

    case 1:
    {  
    printf("Nome    : "); 
    fgets(aluno[i].nomealuno, sizeof(aluno[i].nomealuno), stdin);

    printf("Numero mecanografico  : "); 
    scanf("%d",&aluno[i].numeromeca);

    printf("Data de nascimento    :\n "); 
    printf("dia.:");
    scanf("%d",&aluno[i].dia);  

    printf("mes.:");
    scanf("%d",&aluno[i].mes); 

    printf("ano.:");
    scanf("%d",&aluno[i].ano);

    printf("Rua   : "); 
    fgets(aluno[i].rua, sizeof(aluno[i].rua), stdin);

    printf("N da porta   :"); 
    scanf("%d",&aluno[i].nporta);

    printf("codigo postal:"); 
    scanf("%d",&aluno[i].codigopostal1); 
    printf("-");                                         
    scanf("%d",&aluno[i].codigopostal2);

    printf("Em que curso pertence o aluno?"); 
    fgets(aluno[i].curso, sizeof(aluno[i].curso), stdin);
    }

    .....
```

[image: erro no programa]

Comment: Não poste imagem de código, poste o código propriamente dito. Está impossível de ter uma visão completa do que você escreveu aqui no meu dispositivo

Comment: ok eu vou editar

Comment: esses são os excertos necessarios mas se quiser posso por o codigo completo

Comment: Acho que é só um problema no buffer de leitura. Como você faz para ler a opção?

Comment: ler como maquina ou pessoa? xD

Comment: Ler programaticamente. `scanf`? `fgets` e depois compila na mão o dado?

Comment: Mostrar_Aluno () { printf("Nome.: [%d] %s\n",aluno[i].nomealuno); printf("Numero mecanografico.:%8d\n",aluno[i].numeromeca); printf("Data de Nascimento.:%2d / %2d / %4d\n",aluno[i].dia,aluno[i].mes,aluno[i].ano); printf("Rua .:[%d] %s\n",aluno[i].rua); printf("N da porta .: Nº %3d\n",aluno[i].nporta); printf("codigo postal .: %4d-%3d\n",aluno[i].codigopostal1,aluno[i].codigopostal2); printf("Curso .:[%d] %s\n",aluno[i].curso); }

Comment: sim é basicamente dessa forma

Comment: Eu te perguntei entre duas opções e você me respondeu "sim"?

Comment: entao eu nao entendi o ao que se refere desculpe , consegue explicar de outra forma?

Comment: Você tem uma variável que é usada no `switch`. Essa variável é informada pelo usuário. Como o programa lê essa informação que o usuário fornece?

Comment: a informação é toda dada no case anterior pelo utilizador o programa no inicio nao tem dado nenhum

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que o `scanf` lê apenas o dado que foi indicado e não a quebra de linha digitada, que será apenas o que o `fgets` irá ler de seguida.

Uma solução robusta passa por fazer a leitura do inteiro também com `fgets` utilizando um *buffer* temporário e [`sscanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/):

```
char buff[20];
int numero;
fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), stdin); //lê como string
sscanf(buff, "%d", &numero); //interpreta o inteiro na string lida
```

Se quiser simplificar pode até fazer uma função para encapsular esta lógica sempre que precisar de ler apenas um número:

```
char buff[20];

int lerInt(){
    int numero;
    fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), stdin);
    sscanf(buff, "%d", &numero);
    return numero;
}
```

Aplicando esta lógica o seu código ficaria assim:

```
printf("Nome    : ");
fgets(aluno[i].nomealuno, sizeof(aluno[i].nomealuno), stdin);

printf("Numero mecanografico  : ");
aluno[i].numeromeca = lerInt();

printf("Data de nascimento    :\n ");
printf("dia.:");
aluno[i].dia = lerInt();

printf("mes.:");
aluno[i].mes = lerInt();

printf("ano.:");
aluno[i].ano = lerInt();

printf("Rua   : ");
fgets(aluno[i].rua, sizeof(aluno[i].rua), stdin);

printf("N da porta   :");
aluno[i].nporta = lerInt();

printf("codigo postal:");
aluno[i].codigopostal1 = lerInt();
printf("-");
aluno[i].codigopostal2 = lerInt();

printf("Em que curso pertence o aluno?");
fgets(aluno[i].curso, sizeof(aluno[i].curso), stdin);
```

[Veja o código a correr no Ideone](https://ideone.com/Thb2SF)